# How to translate a flask route with path parameters to gRPC service?

Tags: python, flask, grpc

I'm a little confused on how a simple flask route can translate to a gRPC service reading the [official gRPC introduction](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/).

Suppose I have a flask route like

```py
@app.route("/hello/<string:name>/")
def hello_name():
    return "PLACEHOLDER"
```

If I wanted to define that as a Service in gRPC how would that look? It does not take any request data but instead asks for the data directly in the path. Would it be defined directly as `/hello/<string:name/`? I couldn't seem to find docs on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flask, these are called route params.

In gRPC transcoding (!) see below, you'll need to identify the variable `name` in the definition:

```proto
message HelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

rpc Hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
        get: "/hello/{name}"
    };
}
```

In order to make an HTTP/1 e.g. `GET` request to an HTTP/2 gRPC service, you'll need to use gRPC HTTP Transcoding. This places a proxy between your e.g. Flask client and the gRPC service and converts  the client's HTTP/1 e.g. `GET`s into HTTP/2 gRPC calls. It's non-trivial but it works.

See:

- [Transcoding HTTP/JSON to gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding)
- Envoy [grpc-JSON transcoder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter)

Comment: Amazing, thank you for this extra information :]

Comment: You're welcome!